# Remover caracteres de ponto consecutivos com regex c#

Tags: c#, regex

Tenho este texto:

```
... AAAA ... BBBB ....
```

Preciso de uma regex que transforme os pontos consecutivos em apenas um ponto, sem remover os espaços:

```
. AAAA . BBBB .
```

Fiz uma tentativa:

```
Regex.Replace("... AAAA ... BBBB ....", @"[\.]*\. *", ".", RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

Mas está removendo os espaços do início e ficando assim:

```
.AAAA .BBBB .
```

Answer (score 2):

Basta fazer:

```
Regex.Replace("... AAAA ... BBBB ....", @"\.+", ".")
```

No caso, `\.+` é "[um ou mais](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) pontos", e aí basta substituir por um único ponto.

Ou então:

```
Regex.Replace("... AAAA . BBBB ..", @"\.{2,}", ".")
```

O quantificador `{2,}` significa "dois ou mais", então se tiver uma sequência de dois ou mais pontos, eu troco por apenas um. Acho que faz mais sentido, porque se tiver somente um ponto, esta regex nem faz a troca (a anterior faz, o que é redundante, embora dê o mesmo resultado).

---

Na sua regex você colocou um espaço seguido de `*`, que significa "zero ou mais espaços", por isso ele também estava removendo os espaços. Mas se quer mantê-los, então não os coloque na regex.

Também removi a opção `Multiline`, porque segundo a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=net-6.0) ela só muda o comportamento dos [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$` (além de marcar o início e fim da string, com a opção `Multiline` eles também indicam o início e fim de uma linha). Mas como a regex não usa nenhum deles, então esta opção não faz diferença, e portanto não é necessária.